# Maven builds in mysterious ways

Tags: eclipse, maven, jpa, intellij-idea

I am quite new to Java and Maven and really don't get the building behaviour of maven here.

I have a project where I use JPA with eclipselink, hence I have a `persistence.xml` file under `src/main/java/META-INF`. If I build the project with the goal `jetty:run` in eclipse, everything works great and I find `persistence.xml` under `/target/classes/META-INF` as expected.

But if I try to build the same project with the same goal in the terminal or in IntelliJ, the `META-INF` folder inside target stays empty. I have no idea what the problem could be - maven version changes in all three components (eclipse, bash and intelliJ) changed nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Resources should go under `src/main/resources`. Eclipse is not using Maven directly, rather it emulates it. IntelliJ is using Maven directly, that is why you get the different behaviour.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos What exactly is emulated in Eclipse? This is not about compile on save (which is only supported by Eclipse), but execute a Maven goal.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos So, it should be `src/main/resources/META-INF`?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Oh my gosh - this actually works. You sir are awesome! Thank you very much - I spent hours trying to make sense of it.